# I can't use force reply in telegram api

Tags: php, api, bots, telegram

I have a problem using telegram bot api with php. I send messages easily to user when I set 'reply_markup' to a ReplyKeyboardMarkup but whenever I want to use it as ForceReply bot keeps sending a single message to user over and over.
do you know why it is working like that? what should I do to fix it?

Answer (score 4):

You need to specify your markup like this :

```
$replyMarkup = array(
  'force_reply' => true,
  'selective' => true
);
```

If you need to have custom keyboard you can follow this :

```
$keyboradsValue = array(
   array("button 1","button 2"),
   array("button 3","button 4"),
);
$replyMarkup = array(
  'keyboard' => $keyboradsValue,
  'force_reply' => true,
  'selective' => true
);
```

After that you need to encode your object using json_encode

```
$encodedMarkup = json_encode($replyMarkup, true);
```

Finally you just put above code at your query string at the rest of sendMessage.